# Error: 2:1: unexpected '/' while trying to open R Markdown in PDF

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, rstudio

I have just installed MacTex on my MacBook and also added the library(knitr) package to RStudio, however, every time I try to open my R Markdown using Knit to HTML, or Knit to PDF or Knit to Word, I get the following error in the Render:

```
`Error: 2:1: unexpected '/'
2: /
    ^
Execution halted`
```

I have also attached the code below for reference:

````
---
title: "Exercise"
author: "Georgiana"
date: "2023-10-20"
output:
  word_document: default
  pdf_document: default
---

```{r setup, include = FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```

## Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r pressure, echo = FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```
````

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.

Comment: Hello! I am unable to reproduce your error (albeit on a different OS). Your code renders as expected for me. I suspect this issue may be due to MacTex - it is worth troubleshooting whether that is causing issues. Most R users prefer to use [tinytex](https://yihui.org/tinytex/) to get started knitting documents, I may recommend installing that and seeing if your results change. You can install tinytex via these two commands: `install.packages('tinytex')` and then, `tinytex::install_tinytex()`

Comment: @Quinton.Quagliano I did what you've suggested, but I still get the same error unfortunately.